# Textbox Split and process C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was confuse when id like to explode or in C# called split the textbox with new lines. id like to change. 
facebook.com 
google.com
stacoverflow.com

And that domain can processing by the code belows. I don't think

```
namespace DomainChecker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                string url = textBox1.Text;

                //get string from web
                string rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("https://semanthic.com/api.php?api=masiting&dom=" + url);
                // convert json to the series obj
                Domain Doms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Domain>(rawJSON);
                //
                //Console.WriteLine(Doms.Da);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Domain", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Page Authority", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Domain Authority", typeof(string));
                string P_A = Doms.Pa;
                string D_A = Doms.Da;
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row[0] = url;
                row[1] = P_A;
                row[2] = D_A;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and what's your problem? textBox1.Text contains newline-delimited entries and you want to iterate over them?

Comment: Split with `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: " id like to change. "...change it to what? An array? A string without newlines? Give an example of the expected output. It's unclear what you mean. And are you saying your current code isn't working? It would be helpful it you explain what goes wrong.

Comment: [TextBoxBase.Lines Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) the text in Textbox1 on specific characters, for example linefeeds or carriage return. In your button click you would do this:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnLoad.Enabled = false;
    // spilt the text on LF and/or CR values
    // this gives an array of strings
    string[] urls = textBox1.Text
        .Split(
            new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
        );
    // hand the urls to the background worker
    bgwLoader.RunWorkerAsync(urls);
}
```

It looks like you're going to do a lot of work in that click event. Better hand that to a [`BackgroudWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). The Dowork event of the backgroundworker will now loop over the array of strings with a for each:

```
private void bgwLoader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // initialize the datatable once
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Domain", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Page Authority", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Domain Authority", typeof(string));

    // e.Argument holds the array with urls, don't forget to cast it
    foreach (var url in (string[]) e.Argument)
    {
        var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

        //get string from web
        string rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("https://semanthic.com/api.php?api=masiting&dom=" + url);
        Trace.WriteLine(rawJSON);
        // convert json to the series obj
        Domain Doms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Domain>(rawJSON);

        string P_A = Doms.Pa;
        string D_A = Doms.Da;
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = url;
        row[1] = P_A;
        row[2] = D_A;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    // make sure the Completed event gets our result
    e.Result = dt;
}
```

Now in the runworkercompleted event we can assign the datatable to the datagrid:

```
private void bgwLoader_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Result was set in the last line of the DoWork eventhandler
    dataGridView1.DataSource = (DataTable) e.Result;
    btnLoad.Enabled = true;
}
```

Putting this all together will give you:

[image: loaded in background]

Comment: Drag it from the Toolbox on your form and then hook up the events.

Answer (score 1):

To split `TextBox` to lines, you can rely on [`TextBox.Lines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx), for downloading the string from a url, you can rely on [`DownloadStringTaskAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194294%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and at last for data-binding to `DataGridView` you can rely on `List<T>`. Then the code can be simple and clean like following example:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<MyClass>();
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        foreach (var url in this.textBox1.Lines)
        {
            var content = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
            var myClass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(content);
            list.Add(myClass);
        }
    }
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}
```

Comment: If for any reason you want to know how to split a string to lines (not using a text box), you can use `stringVariable.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)`